# WebStorm uses 100% CPU

Tags: node.js, performance, angular, npm, webstorm

I use WebStorm 11 and developing in Angular2.
The ng serve is working on background from the cmd and the CPU is on 1% work.

When the WebStorm is opening, the CPU jump to 30%-60% and when he start indexing it goes to 100% until the WebStorm crushes.

- I have Intel(R) Core(TM) i503210M CPU @ 2.50GHz 2.50GHz and 8G RAM (I
  don't have RAM problem).
- I excluded `dist` and `node_modules` folders but
  the indexing still takes too long.

WebStorm.exe.vmoptions:

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx1012m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

1. What does the indexing do? Can I turn it off?
2. What is the best way to configure this for small projects?

Comment: indexing is likely to be a bottleneck with your disk FYI, have you got an SSD? the indexing aids with type completion

Comment: I don't have SSD. anyways webstorm keep crushing so I cant do anything.. really annoying.

Comment: If you are on Windows and use a third-party antivirus, try disabling the antivirus and add an exception for webstorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the indexing do? Can I trun it off?

The index process creates a database of your code, enabling fast searches, code completion, symbol lookup, etc.  I don't think you can turn it off, but if you did, WebStorm wouldn't be very useful to you anyway.

This is a well-known issue with WebStorm, but has gotten better with recent versions.  See also:  https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/webstorm-10-improves-the-performance-of-indexing-files/

Answer (score 19):

For people that aren't already, make sure you aren't indexing your dist or www folders.

Right click the folder -> "Mark Directory As" -> "Excluded".

Saved me!

Comment: I didn't know this existed and it is a *significant* performance increase (*for me at least). Tasks that took minutes are down to seconds. Thank you!